# Check out into a folder in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to check out code to a particular folder to an already existing project in eclipse workspace

Answer (score 0):

Try using subclipse. It's the Subversion Plug-in for Eclipse.

Comment: Yes I am using Subclipse , but It will only checkout Code as a whole new Project, I want to check out to a folder of an existing project

Answer (score 0):

//right click your project and go to Team and select the share project.. option

then share you already existing project